# What is the [`expression`] notation used for?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've recently begun learning [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) and stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
handleChange = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target

  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  })
}
```

And I'm somewhat confused, in particular with the following notation:

```
[name]: value,
```

What are the `[ ]` used for?

I understand, that the `const = { name, value } = event.target` is used for object destruction into properties, but the `[name]` notation seems strange and I have not seen any previous reference to it in any of my [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) coding.

Despite my best efforts at googling `[] javascript usage`  and similar, I was unable to find anything of similar sort.

My best guess would be the similarity to  `object["property"]` expression, but this still seems a little odd compared to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), and the notation is basically for using a variable as an object key.